# How is the en-/decoding of the optOut-URL done ? (algorithm)

Tags: civicrm.org

is someone there who knows how the en-/decoding of the optOt-URL is implemented ?

Example:
https://....../crm/civicrm/mailing/optout?reset=1&jid=7&qid=14&h=817b324557dc9cb9

I'd assume that the part "817b324557dc9cb9" is the encoded contact_id 15944 ???

Please help me ;-)
Thanks a lot and kind regards
Dieter

p.s.:
https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/
=> Analyse hash:  817b324557dc9cb9
Hash length: 16
Byte length: 8
Bit length:  64

Based on the length, this hash could have been generated by one of the following hashing functions:
CRC-64
RIPEMD-64
SipHash

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SE!

You can see the construction of the opt-out URL [here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Mailing/BAO/Mailing.php#L1001) and the processing of it [here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Mailing/Form/Optout.php)

- 'jid' is the Job id
- 'qid' is the Queue id
- 'h' is the Hash

The contact_id is not included in the URL but can be looked up via the qid.

Comment: thanks a lot !!! will have a look ;-)

Comment: thanks again Aidan: the related DB-table is
      civicrm_mailing_event_queue (id. job_id)  => contact_id

You made my day ;-)  thx !!!!